# How to declare a xsd with XML.Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm creating an application and i need to create a XML deocument with c#.
im currently using the xml.linq package.

The XML needs some xsd declarations like in the picture second line. I dont know how to get there. Alredy tried it witz some Xname oder XAttribute but it didnt worked exactly that way i wantet it to.

[XML how it needs to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqrJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace can be tricky to add.  I find it is easier to just parse a string to get results.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><c_TemplaceSaver xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"></c_TemplaceSaver>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement c_TemplateSaver = doc.Root;
            c_TemplateSaver.Add(new XElement("ABC", 123));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you veryy much, thats a way it works. Didn't know that it's possible to parse a string like that. Always tried to figure it out with the namespaces but that didn't work quite well.
Thanks! :)